# Create custom column in Linq with sum total of column

Tags: c#, linq

How to Create custom column using linq? coz i alway get error

**Fig. 1**

> Sequence contains more than one element

Data from grid that i selected as context
[image]

My code seems right when removing custom column that iv'e created TotalAmount

```
var studentservices = from ser in result.ToList()
                                          where partStudentServices.Contains(ser.Description)
                                          group ser by ser.Description into gser
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              CCode = gser.FirstOrDefault().Code,
                                              CDescription = gser.FirstOrDefault().Description,
                                              CAmount = gser.Where(s => s.EducationLevel == "College").Select(ns => ns.Amount).Sum(),
                                              HAmount = gser.Where(s => s.EducationLevel == "High School").Select(ns => ns.Amount).Sum(),
                                              GAmount = gser.Where(s => s.EducationLevel == "Grade School").Select(ns => ns.Amount).Sum(),
                                              KAmount = gser.Where(s => s.EducationLevel == "Kinder").Select(ns => ns.Amount).Sum(),
                                              TotalAmount = gser.GroupBy(g => g.Description).Select(ns => ns.Sum(sumn => sumn.Amount))
                                          };


                    d.StudentServicesReport.DataSource = studentservices.ToList();
                    d.xTC_StudentServices_Code.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "CCode");
                    d.xTC_StudentServices_Name.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "CDescription");
                    d.xTC_StudentServices_College.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "CAmount");
                    d.xTC_StudentServices_HS.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "HAmount");
                    d.xTC_StudentServices_GS.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "GAmount");
                    d.xTC_StudentServices_PS.DataBindings.Add("Text", null, "KAmount");
                    d.xTC_StudentServices_CollegeTotal.Text = studentservices.Select(sa => sa.CAmount).Sum().ToString();
                    d.xTC_StudentServices_HSTotal.Text = studentservices.Select(sa => sa.HAmount).Sum().ToString();
                    d.xTC_StudentServices_GSTotal.Text = studentservices.Select(sa => sa.GAmount).Sum().ToString();
                    d.xTC_StudentServices_PSTotal.Text = studentservices.Select(sa => sa.KAmount).Sum().ToString();
                    d.xTC_StudentServices_Total.Text = studentservices.Select(sa => sa.TotalAmount).ToString();
```

but get error see Fig. 1

coz im going to generate a report this should be the output. the red text should be the total amount of each row.
[image]

on printing the error shown on cell that i assign.
[image]

Anyone can help me? I'm stuck on this module about 1 hour.

Comment: What is the error you get? There is _something_ under "Fig 1", but it means nothing to me.

Comment: when im sending the data to report that error on Fig 1 shown on cell of report.. @gunr2171

Comment: Seems you are missing part of the exception.

Comment: @Magnus question edited. please check

Comment: Yeh, that doesn't help. Try debugging the code and see the complete exception.

Comment: @Magnus here the exception message mate.
Sequence contains more than one element.

Comment: You usually get that error message in combination with `.Single` and `.SingleOrDefault`. Perhaps the problem is elsewhere than the code posted.

Comment: yep but without .Single and .SingleOrDefault still the same error. is there's something wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure but it looks like your TotalAmount assignment may be incorrect.  Have you tried the following:

```
 TotalAmount = gser.Sum(sumn => sumn.Amount)
```

I believe that the way that you have it, .Select returns an IEnumerable  and you are attempting to assign that as the value of your label so it is just displaying the type.

Comment: ohh i got it mate it's IEnumerable. rrhhhhh thanks a lot.. problem solve